# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, finance

I am trying to run a flask project, I get the following error.

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from anomalies import anomalies_result_visualization
  File "D:\coursework\anomalies\anomalies_result_visualization.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance as finance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'
```

My requirements.txt is as follows.

```
Flask==0.12.1
matplotlib==1.4.3
six
pandas
statsmodels
arch
sklearn
mpld3
```

Any help would be welcomed and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You should install `matplotlib` as it says

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html: This module is deprecated in 2.0 and has been moved to a module called mpl_finance.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters it actually runs, but gives some errors. I wanted to know whether matplotlib.finance and mpl_finance are same?

Comment: @NimmiRashinika - it is now maintained, and there is a new version here: https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Comment: Thank you all for the support